# Existing implementations of OSGi Configuration Admin Service?

Tags: java, configuration, osgi

We are considering to use Configuration Admin Service as a primary API for configuring components in our OSGi-based application. It would be nice if we could reuse some existing implementation so I'm trying to investigate and evaluate the most popular ones. I know there is:

- [Apache Felix Config Admin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-configuration-admin-service.html) (org.apache.felix.cm)
- [Equinox Config Admin](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/bundles/) (org.eclipse.equinox.cm)

Are there any other implementations to be considered?

Also I was not able to find any good documentation for these implementations. I would be mainly interested in the implementation-specific details. For example I was wondering how different implementations persist the configuration data (e.g. multiple property files? XML file? multiple XML files? database?, ...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three public implementations I know of are

- [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-configuration-admin-service.html)
- Equinox […source](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.equinox/compendium/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.cm/src) (this has moved recently)
- Knopflerfish […front page](http://www.knopflerfish.org/snapshots/2.3.2.snapshot_trunk_2751/docs/components.html#knopflerfish) and […source](https://www.knopflerfish.org/svn/knopflerfish.org/trunk/osgi/bundles/cm)

Equinox's implementation of the `ConfigurationAdmin` service appears not to support fine control over the persistence policy, as Felix's does, and the Knopflerfish implementation looks (I've only read the source briefly) similar to Equinox's.

The Felix one appears to be the most recently updated and the most reliable.

At present these are the only ones I can find; at dm Server we made the decision to use Felix's bundle, and this is now obtainable from the [SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/), where you can quick-search for `Apache Felix` or `ConfigAdmin`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, we decided to use Felix Config Admin implementation as well (together with our own persistence strategy).

Answer (score 7):

Felix's Configuration Admin has a [default implementation](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/felix/releases/org.apache.felix.configadmin-1.0.8/src/main/java/org/apache/felix/cm/file/FilePersistenceManager.java?revision=734642) that persists to the file system, but they define a service interface ([org.apache.felix.cm.PersistenceManager](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/felix/releases/org.apache.felix.configadmin-1.0.8/src/main/java/org/apache/felix/cm/PersistenceManager.java?revision=734642&view=markup)) for alternative backends that you could plug in instead.

The default implementation does the following:

> The FilePersistenceManager class stores configuration data in
>   properties-like files inside a given directory. All configuration files are
>   located in the same directory.
>
> Configuration files are created in the configuration directory by appending
>   the extension ".config" to the PID of the configuration. The PID
>   is converted into a relative path name by replacing enclosed dots to slashes.
>   Non-symbolic-name characters in the PID are encoded with their
>   Unicode character code in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the answer further: I personally also prefer the Felix implementation. For an example of how to change the way storage occurs at the back-end using a PersistenceManager, see also [this](http://www.avineas.org/index.php?page=cm-persister) implementation that uses standard Java property files as backing storage. Has some limitations, but at least allows you to store your configuration with your application and apart from your OSGi framework implementation.